# VSCode Preview in default browser doesn't show the project but it shows the code itself (HTML, CSS files), the file are saved in a GitHub repository

Tags: html, git, github, visual-studio-code

I am definitely new here and I am working on my first projects.

I am using VSCode editor and my default preview browser doesn't work. I'am working on static files html and css, saved in a folder of a repository hosted in GitHub. I have installed two extensions: HTML preview and Live server which are updated. When I go on preview, the browser page shows me the html code I've written instead of the result...

I tried to sort the issued out doing these:

• I used HTML boilerplate extension because I thought was missing something on that I wrote by myself.

• I've unistalled and re-installed Live Server and HTML Preview

• I set Crome as default Browser in Live server setting and on setting.Json file.

• I have restarted my computer, VSCode, and empty Crome cache.

• I am using Git, so I did a test: I open a new .html file on Vscode, in the same folder (without adding it to the GitHub repository) and I open it in browser preview and IT WORKED!!
I think the issue is there, can someone help me???Maybe it is just a setting...hope to don't waste your time.

Comment: Try installing open in browser plugin.

Comment: you can share HTML code here in code snippet

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the correct file **extension** something we save files in **txt** format something like this **index.html.txt**
[image]

and the **preview** of this **file** is something like this

[image]

let me know if this is the **problem** and for further can you provide the ss of your **file extension** and **code**

Comment: Hi MAKSTYLE119 thank you for your help, I've checked and the file was a .txt file with html only extension. So I resolve the issue, everything works now!! Thanks